# How can I collapse a struct array?

Tags: swift

I have a struct for my items:

```
struct item: Decodable {
    var category_id: Int
    var name: String
}
```

Which I'm receiving through `JSONDecoder().decode into an array (items: [item])`.

And I'd like to collapse it into a structure like this:

```
struct collapsed{
    var category_id = Int()
    var items = [String]()
}
```

So that I can loop through it more conveniently. How can I do that?

So I have this variable:

```
items: [item]
```

Which looks like this:

```
items
[0]
 -category_id: 0
 -name: "item1"
[1]
 -category_id: 1
 -name: "item2"
[2]
 -category_id: 0
 -name: "item3"
[3]
 -category_id: 1
 -name: "item4"
[4]
 -category_id: 0
 -name: "item5"
```

And I want to collapse it to this:

```
collapseditems: [collapsed]
```

Which should look something like this:

```
collapseditems
[0]
 -category_id: 0
 -items:
  [0]: "item1"
  [1]: "item3"
  [2]: "item5"
[1]
 -category_id: 1
 -items:
  [0]: "item2"
  [1]: "item4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using below code.

```
var sortedList: [sorted] = []

for i in item {
    if let index = sortedList.index(where: { $0.category_id == i.category_id }) {
        sortedList[index].items.append(i.name)
    } else {
        sortedList.append(sorted(category_id: i.category_id, items: [i.name]))
    }
}

print(sortedList)
```

Comment: It's missing the first item in each category.

Comment: @Gimmethe411 Can you show me the result so i can give you a solution

Comment: In the expected result in my question, it is missing "item1" and "item2"

Comment: @Gimmethe411 But i'm getting complete result in above solution

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't know where I made a mistake. Now I've confirmed it shows all items.

Comment: @Gimmethe411 No worry We are developers, We made for mistakes and learn.

Answer (score 2):

First thing - struct names should start with uppercase letters.

There are a few ways you can translate your array of `Item` to an array of `Collapsed`. Here is one approach that first groups the array of `Item` into a dictionary keyed by `category_id`. Then that dictionary is mapped into an array of `Collapsed`. Finally that array is sorted by `category_id`.

```
struct Item: Decodable {
    var category_id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct Collapsed {
    let category_id: Int
    var items: [String]
}

// Your array of Item - here is some test data
let items: [Item] = [
    Item(category_id: 0, name: "item1"),
    Item(category_id: 1, name: "item2"),
    Item(category_id: 0, name: "item3"),
    Item(category_id: 1, name: "item4"),
    Item(category_id: 0, name: "item5")
]

// Create a dictionary where the keys are category_id and the values are an array of Item with the same category_id
let mapping = Dictionary(grouping: items, by: { $0.category_id })
// Map that dictionary into an array of Sorted and then sort that array by category_id
let collapsedItems: [Collapsed] = mapping
    .map { Collapsed(category_id: $0.key, items: $0.value.map { $0.name }) }
    .sorted { $0.category_id < $1.category_id }
```

Answer (score 0):

For first question, do you want to make a sorted list of `item` struct?
If yes, you can use `sorted` method of `Array` like this.

```
let sorted = items.sorted { $0.category_id < $1.category_id }
```

For Second question, first struct has default value for its properties, but second one hasn't. Second one, therefore, does NOT offer an empty constructor.

Comment: If I do that then sorted is of type [item]. But I need a variable of type [sorted]. So I want to convert from [item] -> [sorted]. So like items: [item] -> sorteditems: [sorted].